# How to search a string for another string using HTBasic

Tags: basic

I am trying to create a program which will search a string for another string, and return the string directly after that string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the POS function to find the substring. Give it the string to search and the string you're looking for and it will return the position it's found at:

- POS( S$, T$ )

  - S$ is the string you're searching
  - T$ is the string you're looking for
  - Return value is the position it's found at, or 0 if not found.

The strings are treated as arrays of characters.

```
A$="hello"
B$=A$[3,4]  ! B$ will become "ll"
C$=A$[2]    ! C$ will become "ello"
```

To get everything following the found substring you can use something like this:

```
1000 DIM A$[72]
1020 A$="Hello World, & goodbye." ! String to search
1040 T$="World, "                 ! String to look for
1060 L=LEN(T$)
1080 PRINT A$[L+POS(A$,T$)]
1100 END
```

Running this should give this result:

```
& goodbye.
```